# Wordpress sql insert with form

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to insert data to sql table that i create using $wpdb

I've tried many things but none of them work for me.
Any ideas?
(i have an id column with auto increment)

```
<?php /* Template Name: My Custom Page */ 
require_once("header.php");
                    ?>    
<div class="wrap">

      <form action="" method="post">
          FFFirstName <input type="text" name="nametxt" value="" /><br/>

          <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
          <?php   
          if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
              {
                global $wpdb;  
                  $firstName = $_POST["nametxt"];
                    echo $firstName;
         $table = $wpdb->prefix."invoice";  
        $wpdb->insert($table,array('name' => $firstName ));
        }

 $wpdb->print_error(); 
  $wpdb->show_errors();     
     ?>   
     </div>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> ALTER TABLE wp_invoice MODIFY COLUMN ID INT(5) auto_increment

```
<?php 
/* 
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/ 


      if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
          {
            global $wpdb;  
            $firstName = $_POST["nametxt"];
            echo $firstName;
            $table = $wpdb->prefix."invoice";  
            $wpdb->insert($table,array('name' => $firstName ));
       }

    $wpdb->print_error(); 
    $wpdb->show_errors();     
   ?> 
  <?php require_once("header.php");?>
<div class="wrap">

      <form action="" method="post">
      FFFirstName <input type="text" name="nametxt" value="" /><br/>

      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

</div>
```

Comment: do you have `name` field in invoice table?

Comment: firstname echo work. and yes i have name field in invoice table

Comment: can you share me table structure?

Comment: I have modified this line ` <input name="Submit"` to ` <input name="submit"` ?

Comment: yes, i just copied your code, and its seems that the post does work, because echo show $firstname

Comment: you need to add auto increment for this table `wp_invoice`

Comment: you forgot the auto increment

Answer (score 0):

table structure

```
table `wp_invoice`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_invoice` (
  `ID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_invoice`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_invoice` (`ID`, `name`) VALUES
(2, 'shasy'),
(0, 'shay');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `wp_invoice`
--
ALTER TABLE `wp_invoice`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score -1):

global $firstName = $_POST["nametxt"];